# How do I enforce a specific custom post type on the loop

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, author-template

I am developing a blog where the main posts are of a custom post type.

Let's assume it is a Book custom post type.

I want the /author/admin page to list the books of the author admin, but instead, it goes and searches for Posts of admin, which is the built-in basic post type.

How do I make my custom post type Book to be used in all such index queries? (main page, author, search, etc).

Answer (score 5):

You can modify all main queries *before* they happen via the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action and a check if [`is_main_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query):

```
function wpa75492_post_type_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'book' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa75492_post_type_query' );
```

Answer (score -2):

use the parameter post_type=your-custom-post-type-slug-here

for example if your post type slug is "product" then use the code like:

```
query_post("post_type=product");
```

Comment: Additionally if you want to keep default post types too use:
[code]
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'post_type' => 'product' ) );
query_posts( $args );
[/code]
more details: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: I strongly advise against the use of `query_post`, it causes more problems than its worth, Milo's answer demonstrates the correct alternative to `query_post`

Answer (score -2):

You need to query the posts from that specific post type before the loop.  So, on your author archive page, or any page template, add this before the loop:

```
query_posts(array(
    'post_type'   => 'book_posttype',
    'author_name' => 'mark'
));
```

Query_posts can take other parameters as well.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

It can use the same parameters as WP_query.  One of which is author_name.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

You can also add an author page template which you will place this query in and the loop.  It would be a page in your theme directory called, author-mark.php or whatever the name is.